# Extjs how to parse jsonP response

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

Using Ext5 I am trying to send a jsonp request to http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts .

This is my store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.example.Post',
{
        storeId: 'Post',
        model: 'MyApp.model.example.Post',
        proxy:
        {
                type: 'jsonp',
                url: 'http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
                noCache: false,
                pageParam: false, // to remove param "page"
                startParam: false, // to remove param "start"
                limitParam: false, // to remove param "limit"
        },
        autoLoad: true
});
```

Using Fiddler Web Debugger I can inspect the http request/response. 
The url request is: 
http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1

You can inspect the response using the above url. 
My problem is how to parse the response from the server.

Comment: One does not parse json**p** - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP ... and if that's indeed the URL you are getting, it will never work (everything after `callback1` is the problem there)

Comment: Ok, but if the server respond correctly why my Ext application can not populate my models?

Comment: so are you saying that the server responds incorrectly? it seems strange

Comment: Ok, can you show me a valid configuration?

Comment: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?callback=Ext.data.JsonP.callback1 is the correct url

Comment: well that was a waste of time then

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like the `_dc` parameter for caching is causing the issue from what i can tell from your url endpoint.

You do not need to parse the `JsonP` request that is handled for you in the methods.

Here is a simple example of a `Ext.data.JsonP.request` that is functioning.  And a [fiddle of the working example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/t5t).

```
Ext.data.JsonP.request({
        'url': 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts',
        disableCaching : false,
        success: function (result, request) {
            //success
            console.log(result, request);
        }
    });
```

Sencha docs is a great resource, here is the [link](https://bt.associatesys.local/documentation/extjs5/ext-docs-5.0/apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.JsonP-property-disableCaching) to the JsonP doc regarding the caching.  If you turn this property back to `true` you'll see that no results are returned from your endpoint.